# Perform graphQL query with result from another graphQL query

Tags: graphql

I have two queries I want to execute:

```
{
    items(name: "jim") {
        id
    }
}
```

Which returns a list of ids on `Item`:

```
[
{"id": 123}
...
]
```

For each one of these ids, I need to lookup another object, `ItemDetail`

```
itemDetail(id: 123) {
    name
    description
}
```

Note that `ItemDetail` is not a property of `Item` :/

Is it possible to combine these queries together into a single query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192685/use-query-result-as-argument-in-next-level-in-graphql

Comment: Why would "ItemDetail" be a property of Item? From your query, I would assume `name` and `description` are properties of Item. If not, the API you've been provided made poor decisions.